# SSH connection to AWS EC2 servers terminate often

Tags: 12.04, 11.10, ssh, cloud

I am using ubuntu os as i am trying to cloud machine. SSH connection to AWS EC2 servers terminate often, what configuration needs to be modified so that we could minimize the remote shell from being terminated.

Answer (score 1):

in your `.ssh` folder, add a file named `config` with your favorite editor (gedit or whatever). In the file named `config` add the following lines:

```
Host myEC2instance
User blue
Hostname someDNSname.from.amazon.com
ServerAliveInterval 5
```

This permits ssh to be used as:

```
$ ssh myEC2instance
```

and you will be asked for your keyphrase once, and no more until you log off (`CTRL+D`).

Here are some additional details:

**HostName**

Specifies the real host name to log into.  This can be used to specify nicknames or abbreviations for hosts.  The default is the name given on the command line.  Numeric IP addresses are also permitted (both on the command line and in HostName specifications).

**ServerAliveInterval**

Sets a timeout interval in seconds after which if no data has been received from the server, ssh(1) will send a message through the encrypted channel to request a response from the server.  The default is 0, indicating that these messages will not be sent to the server, or 300 if the BatchMode option is set.  This option applies to protocol version 2 only.  ProtocolKeepAlives and SetupTimeOut are Debian-specific compatibility aliases for this option.

Please visit [SSHconfig manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man5/ssh_config.5.html) for more details.

Comment: I have done these things
On the server, login as root and edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and add the line:

`ClientAliveInterval 60`

&
Alternatively on the client edit /etc/ssh/ssh_config (if you have root and want it for all users) or `~/.ssh/config` and add the line:

`ServerAliveInterval 60`

but that doesn't seem to worked that much. Do let me know the any other to resolve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Excuse me for asking this, but have you exchanged keys with the server or are you logging in using passwords?
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html